# Azure blob storage - Access tier change

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

We currently have a legacy blob storage account of 600TB configured as Standard\Hot tier which has archived backups. As part of cost optimization, we want to change the access tier to Cool on the blob storage account. Does this incur data movement ? As per documentation, it says the change is instantaneous. Does that mean hot to cool will not have any data transfer and incur no additional charges in pricing?

Answer (score 0):

it's done in background by Microsoft but you have to pay for it.

take a look here:

[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/access-tiers-overview#changing-a-blobs-access-tier)

> When a blob is uploaded or moved between tiers, it is charged at the
> corresponding rate immediately upon upload or tier change.

> When a blob is moved to a cooler tier (Hot to Cool, Hot to Archive, or
> Cool to Archive), the operation is billed as a write operation to the
> destination tier, where the write operation (per 10,000) and data
> write (per GB) charges of the destination tier apply.